# Indexing timeseries by date string

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Given a timeseries, `s`, with a datetime index I expected to be able to index the timeseries by the date string. Am I misunderstanding how this should work?

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csvs=SPY&d=12&e=4&f=2012&g=d&a=01&b=01&c=2001&ignore=.csv'  
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)  
s = df['Close']
s['2012-12-04']
```

Result:

```
TimeSeriesError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-244-e2ccd4ecce94> in <module>()
      2 df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)  
      3 s = df['Close']  
----> 4 s['2012-12-04']

    G:\Python27-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    468     def __getitem__(self, key):
    469         try:
--> 470             return self.index.get_value(self, key)
    471         except InvalidIndexError:
    472             pass

    G:\Python27-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.pyc in get_value(self, series, key)  

   1030 
   1031             try:
-> 1032                 loc = self._get_string_slice(key)
   1033                 return series[loc]
   1034             except (TypeError, ValueError, KeyError):

G:\Python27-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.pyc in _get_string_slice(self, key)
   1077         asdt, parsed, reso = parse_time_string(key, freq)
   1078         key = asdt
-> 1079         loc = self._partial_date_slice(reso, parsed)
   1080         return loc
   1081 

G:\Python27-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.pyc in _partial_date_slice(self, reso, parsed)
    992     def _partial_date_slice(self, reso, parsed):
    993         if not self.is_monotonic:
--> 994             raise TimeSeriesError('Partial indexing only valid for ordered '
    995                                   'time series.')
    996 

TimeSeriesError: Partial indexing only valid for ordered time series.
```

To be more specific (and perhaps pedantic..), what's the difference between the 2 Timeseries here:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?        s=SPY&d=12&e=4&f=2012&g=d&a=01&b=01&c=2001&ignore=.csv'
s = pd.read_csv(url, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)['Close']
rng = date_range(start='2011-01-01', end='2011-12-31')
ts = Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
print ts.__class__
print ts.index[0].__class__
print s1.__class__
print s1.index[0].__class__
print ts[ts.index[0]]
print s[s.index[0]]
print ts['2011-01-01']
try:
    print s['2012-12-05']
except:
    print "doesn't work"
```

Result:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.TimeSeries'>
<class 'pandas.lib.Timestamp'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.TimeSeries'>
<class 'pandas.lib.Timestamp'>
-0.608673793503
141.5
-0.608673793503
doesn't work
```

Comment: I get a 404 error on that url. It's easier if you copy in some of the table, or even better the output of `df.to_dict()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try indexing with a `Timestamp` object:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from pandas.lib import Timestamp
>>> url = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=SPY&d=12&e=4&f=2012&g=d&a=01&b=01&c=2001&ignore=.csv'
>>> df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
>>> s = df['Close']
>>> s[Timestamp('2012-12-04')]
141.25
```

Comment: Yes, thanks, I can see that that would work. My question is why s['2012-12-04'] doesn't. Is it a bug, or is that how it should work for a Timeseries with a Datetime index?

Comment: @user1878647 it has a Timestamp index not a datetime, although you can also lookup using it's datetime. What you can't do is look up using a string in an unknown date-format (for one thing, it may be unclear which date it should be interpreted as). I would say it's not a bug.

Comment: @hayden both ts and s in the example above have Timestamp indices, but behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

When the time series is **not ordered** and you give a partial timestamp (e.g. a date, rather than a datetime) it's not clear which datetime should be selected.

It can't be assumed that there is only one datetime object per date, although there are in this example, here there are several options but it seems safer to throw an error here rather than guess a users motives. (We could return a series/list similar to `.ix['2011-01']`, but this may be confusing if returning a number in other cases. We could try to return a "closest match"... but this doesn't really make sense either.)

**In an ordered case it's easier, we pick the first datetime with the selected date.**

You can see in this behaviour in this simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn
from random import shuffle
rng = pd.date_range(start='2011-01-01', end='2011-12-31')
rng2 = list(rng)
shuffle(rng2) # not in order
rng3 = list(rng)
del rng3[20] # in order, but no freq

ts = pd.Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng)
ts2 = pd.Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng2)
ts3 = pd.Series(randn(len(rng)-1), index=rng3)

ts.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2011-12-31 00:00:00]
Length: 365, Freq: D, Timezone: None

ts['2011-01-01']
# -1.1454418070543406

ts2.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-04-16 00:00:00, ..., 2011-03-10 00:00:00]
Length: 365, Freq: None, Timezone: None

ts2['2011-01-01']
#...error which you describe
TimeSeriesError: Partial indexing only valid for ordered time series

ts3.index
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2011-01-01 00:00:00, ..., 2011-12-31 00:00:00]
Length: 364, Freq: None, Timezone: None

ts3['2011-01-01']
1.7631554507355987


rng4 = pd.date_range(start='2011-01-01', end='2011-01-31', freq='H')
ts4 = pd.Series(randn(len(rng4)), index=rng4)

ts4['2011-01-01'] == ts4[0]
# True # it picks the first element with that date
```

*I don't think this is a bug, nevertheless I posted it as [an issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2437).*

Answer (score 0):

While the pandas tutorial was instructive, I think the original question posed deserves a direct answer. I ran into the same problem converting Yahoo chart info to a DataFrame that could be sliced, etc. I found that the only thing that was required was:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def dt_parser(date): 
return dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d') + dt.timedelta(hours=16)

url = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csvs=SPY&d=12&e=4&f=2012&g=d&a=01&b=01&c=2001&ignore=.csv'  
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0, parse_dates=True, date_parser=dt_parser)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
s = df['Close']
s['2012-12-04']     # now should work
```

The "trick" was to include my own date_parser. I'm guessing that there is some better way to do this within read_csv, but this at least produced a DataFrame that was indexed and could be sliced.