# Reading data from csv file into time series with pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, time-series

My goal is to read EURUSD [**data**](http://fxhistoricaldata.com/EURUSD/) (daily) into a time series object where I can easily slice-and-dice, aggregate, and resample the information based on irregular-ish time frames.  This is most likely a simple answer.  I'm working out of Python for Data Analysis but can't seem to bridge the gap.

After downloading and unzipping the [**data**](http://fxhistoricaldata.com/EURUSD/), I run the following code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('EURUSD_day.csv', parse_dates = {'Timestamp' : ['<DATE>', '<TIME>']}, index_col = 'Timestamp')
```

So far so good.  I now have a nice data frame with Timestamps as the index.

However, the book implies (p. 295) that I should be able to subset the data, as follows, to look at all the data from the year 2001.

```
>>> df['2001']
```

But, that doesn't work.

Reading this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13737992/indexing-timeseries-by-date-string) tells me that I could import Timestamp:

```
>>> from pandas.lib import Timestamp
>>> s = df['<CLOSE>']
```

Which seems to work for a particular day:

```
>>> s[Timestamp('2001-01-04)]
0.9506999999
```

Yet, the following code yields a single value for my desired range of all data from year 2001.

```
>>> s[Timestamp('2001')]
0.8959
```

I know I am missing something simple, something basic.  Can anyone help?

Thank you,
Brian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example on pg. 295 is being performed on Series object which is why indexing with the year works.  With a DataFrame you would want `df.ix['2001']` to achieve the same results.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  Your answer works wonderfully for a data frame.  How would I import the data into a Series object?

Comment: A series is a simple one dimensional array-like object.  It has an index and values associated with each index.  A DataFrame is made up of multiple Series objects (each column is a Series).  So to get a Series from your DataFrame you can select any individual column like `df["Column Name"]` and the result will be a series.  Or to access a value in that column by index, try `df["Column Name"]['2001']`.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I knew that I was missing something **basic**, and you nailed it.  I can't tell you how much I appreciate your clear and concise explanation.

Comment: @Brian: you don't strictly need to upvote any answers (click upward-facing arrow), but since this answer -- and related comments -- helped you out a lot you should consider upvoting so that the community will be more likely to trust this user accordingly in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all of the columns, then `df.ix['2001']`.

If you're interested only in "CLOSE", since you already did `s = df['<CLOSE>']`, you can get the 2001 values by `s['2001']`